# HandsOnTable load data including formulas

Tags: reactjs, typescript, handsontable, react-tsx

I have handsonTable which is getting data as array of array. I applied some formulas and saved the data. now I want to load that data directly into handsonTable component in ReactJs. problem is its not showing value instead it shows formula as plain text (=sum(A:B)).

`setData([[3,5,'=sum(A1:B1)'],['=A1']])`

this will not be calculated instead formula will be recalculated if I double click cell C1 and then click somewhere else… this step calculates the value but still it will give wrong answer (i.e. C1=13), I will get correct answer only if I double click and unFocus both cells (i.e A1,B1)…

I am simply passing array of array to `<HotTable />` component and when I have to reload, I fetch data from server, mix some new data on **Front End** and set the Global State (Zustand). [Question asked on official blog](https://forum.handsontable.com/t/load-data-array-of-arrays-into-handsontable-from-database-also-keep-the-formulas-applied-before-saving/6496/8) containing Fiddle Example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a bug in V12 of handsontable.
[GH Issue 10011](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/10011)